# Passing value from fragment to another error

Tags: java, android, json

i got a value from a json response and i need to send it to an other fragment to use it.

```
  public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            Log.i("Responsestring", response.body().toString());
                            Log.i("onSuccess", response.body().toString());

                            String jsonresponse = response.body().toString();

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonresponse);

                                if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                                    JSONObject jsonData = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                                   Integer id = jsonData.getInt("id");
                                   Log.i("ID", String.valueOf(id));
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                    Intent intent;
                                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityListEvents.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                   Log.i("DATA", jsonObject.getString("data"));
                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putInt("id", id);
                                    Log.i("ID BUNDEL", String.valueOf(id));
                                    Profile_Fragment mFragment_B = new Profile_Fragment();
                                    mFragment_B.setArguments(bundle);
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Here, im getting the value that i need, i use bundle to send it to the profile fragment.

My profile fragment

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false);
        initViews();
        setListeners();
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        int id = bundle.getInt("id");
        Log.i("ID REC",String.valueOf(id));

        return view;
    }
```

i need the id to call it in updateUsers

```
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(UpdateProfile.UPDPRO)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        UpdateProfile api = retrofit.create(UpdateProfile.class);
        Call<String> call = api.UpdateUsers(id,name,prenom,adresse,email,numtel);
```

im getting this error

> 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

i have searched for the problem and i didn't fix it.

Comment: can you add your error log

Comment: If both the fragments are in viewpager in same activity, then you have to pass the value to parent activity then to the other fragment

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.toutpartager.Profile_Fragment.onCreateView(Profile_Fragment.java:41)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)

Comment: why you are starting activity and then doing fragment transaction ?

Comment: also arguments are set to fragment but  fragment transaction is missing ?

Comment: @akshay_shahane im getting the code from a question in this forum and i test it

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what are you trying to achieve? Currently looking at your code, you are starting an activity and than create a new Fragment and set arguments to it without doing anything else with it.

Comment: Intent intent;
                                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityListEvents.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                   Log.i("DATA", jsonObject.getString("data"));
                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putInt("id", id);
                                    Profile_Fragment mFragment_B = new Profile_Fragment();
                                    mFragment_B.setArguments(bundle);

Comment: check this part

Comment: @h4rd4r7c0r3 i need to achieve the id from the login fragment to use it in the profile fragment.

Comment: You need to start a new activity or show Profile Fragment? What is the point of starting ActivityListEvents ?

Comment: @h4rd4r7c0r3 the ActivityListEvent start from login fragment. From ActivityListEvent i can access for profile fragment

Comment: Is ActivityListEvent the place where you attach. your profile fragment?

Comment: @h4rd4r7c0r3 yes

Comment: @h4rd4r7c0r3  i have already send the id from the login fragment to the ActivityListEvent

Answer (score 0):

as i see your  code first you have to pass the data into

```
  Intent  intent = new Intent(getActivity(), 
   ActivityListEvents.class);
 intent.putExtras("yourKey",""+yourvalue)     
 startActivity(intent);
```

after this get data into your ActivityListEvents and than call this if your fragment start from ActivityListEvents

```
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putInt("id", id);
                                Log.i("ID BUNDEL", String.valueOf(id));
                                Profile_Fragment mFragment_B = new Profile_Fragment();
                                mFragment_B.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: i didn't understand you well, should i write `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putInt("id", id);
                                Log.i("ID BUNDEL", String.valueOf(id));
                                Profile_Fragment mFragment_B = new Profile_Fragment();
                                mFragment_B.setArguments(bundle);` in my ActivityList or in my profile fragment

Comment: Profile_Fragment where you load this fragment i mean in which activity

Comment: in ActivityListEvent
`
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_events);

logout=findViewById(R.id.logout);
update=findViewById(R.id.update);
update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
 fragmentManager
  .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frameContainer, new Profile_Fragment()).commit();

    }
});
`

Comment: yaah than first you have to pass this data from first activity to second activity and than from  second you pass the data into fragment than its work understand  activity->ActivityListEvent->Profile_Fragment

Comment: So i need to use the bundle in the ActivityListEvent ?

Comment: i got the id in my ActivtyListEvent successfully, in my profile fragment i use `  int id = getArguments().getInt("id"); ` but still i have the same problem **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle != null)
        {
            id = bundle.getInt("id");
        }
        bundle.putInt("id", id);
        Log.i("IDFROM ",String.valueOf(id));

        Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
        bundle1.putInt("id",id);
        final Profile_Fragment fragobj = new Profile_Fragment();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle1);
```

My Fragment

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        int id = bundle.getInt("id");
```